# SQL Server database truncated a big base64 string

Tags: c#, blazor

I working on a uploading image upload from Blazor webassembly project, I send the IFormFile file  to an API that convert the image to base64 string and then I called an sql stored procedure to  save the string in a SQL Server database table.

The type of the base64 string column in the table is NVARCHAR(MAX) but I noticed when the string is saved, SQL truncates the string
note : I changed the data type of column to VARCHAR(MAX) or ntext but same problem.
when I tried to insert from sql studio management same problem
here is the  code

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await image.File.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            string base64String;
            using (var fs1 = image.File.OpenReadStream())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fs1.CopyTo(ms);
                image.UploadFile = ms.ToArray();
            }

          
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(image.UploadFile);
```

wwhen I take the value of base64String  and see if the image is correct via
https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
the image appears correctly
so I thing the problem in sql.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[InsertCustomerFiles]

@CustomerID int,
@UploadFile nvarchar(MAX)


as

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[CustomoerFiles]
(      [CustomerID]
      ,[UploadFile])

      values
      (@CustomerID
      ,@UploadFile
      )
```

how I call stored procedure from asp.net core webapi

```
 using (IDbConnection CISConnection = DbConnection)
            {
                try
                {

                    DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                    // Form Consent
                    parameters.Add("CustomerID", int.Parse(image.CustomerID));
                    parameters.Add("FileName", image.FileName);
                    parameters.Add("FilePath", filePath);
                    parameters.Add("FileType", int.Parse(image.FileType));
                    parameters.Add("UploadFile", base64String);
                      CISConnection.ExecuteReader("InsertCustomerFiles", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
                // return SqlMapper.Query<SkinType>(con, "GetSkinType", param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

            }
```

Comment: After you insert it, please check the length (using both `LEN` and `DATALENGTH`). Please share that value in your question, alongside the value of `base64String.Length`.

Comment: @mjwills
it's truncated because when I select and check the result with the original string it's not the same.

Comment: Tell me _exactly_ how you checked it. What is the `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` value?

Comment: I do 
SELECT  
      [CustomerID]
      ,[UploadFile]
  FROM dbo.[CustomoerFiles]
then I past the result of Uploadfile to https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
and see that the image is truncated.

Comment: I do select using SSMS